Will expanding space rupture an empty box floating in outer space
Under the theory that space itself is expanding, but the space inside of atoms and molecules doesn't expand because nuclear and electromagnetic bonding forces exceed the forces that expand space, would a closed empty box floating in outer space eventually rupture because of the expanding space inside of it?

The box would only be ripped apart if dark energy is "phantom energy", which increases in energy density as the Universe expands. In that case, the destruction of the box would occur right before the Big Rip.
If the dark energy is a cosmological constant (which is consistent with current data), then its energy density remains constant over time, and so does the repulsive influence it exerts on a box of fixed volume. Thus, a box that survives now will survive indefinitely (neglecting material degradation). For a spherical box of radius $r$ (which I assume to be much smaller than the cosmological horizon), dark energy at its measured value induces an outward gravitational acceleration of
$$g=H_0^2\Omega_\Lambda r\simeq (3\times 10^{-36}\mathrm{sec}^{-2})r,$$ where $H_0\simeq 68$ km/s/Mpc is the Hubble constant and $\Omega_\Lambda\simeq 0.69$ is the dark energy density parameter. For example, this means that if the radius were 1 meter, the acceleration would be $3\times 10^{-36} \mathrm{m}/\mathrm{s}^2$ (36.5 orders of magnitude weaker than Earth's surface gravity). Indeed, for any object denser than
$$\frac{3H_0^2}{4\pi G}\Omega_\Lambda\simeq 10^{-29}~\text{gram}/\text{cm}^3\simeq 7~\text{keV}/\text{cm}^3$$
($10^{-29}$ times the density of water), its own self-gravity is stronger than dark energy's repulsion.
Note that these effects arise from gravitational repulsion from the dark energy. "Expanding space" is not itself a physical phenomenon; as discussed in other answers:

Space expansion is a description of the coordinates and not the physics.
There is no concept of "expanding space" in general relativity.
Expansion of space is not distinguishable from objects moving away.

For example, without dark energy, there would be no expansion force on the box, even as the Universe expands.

Thank you Sten. Under your example where if the box survives now it will survive indefinitely, would that indicate that the size and composition of the box is relevant, where size could be increased to an equilibrium point whereby accumulated forces of space expansion exactly equal the nuclear and electromagnetic binding forces of the matter the box is composed of, allowing the box to survive forever, but if the box is made any bigger it would immediately rupture? Just wondering if an experiment could be devised using cardboard boxes to see if a certain size ruptures and smaller size survives.

Also wondering if we already have measurements of the the force of expanding space versus nuclear and electromagnetic force of the matter the box is composed of to allow for a prediction of what the equilibrium size should be?

@mdswartz I might be wrong, but I don't think one should think about it in terms of classical force. Think about "the big rip" scenarios in terms of an effective weakening of the other forces. The speed of sound in materials would start decreasing and it would, eventually, become zero. At that point all internal cohesion of a classical object would be lost and it would literally start flowing apart like as if it was melting.

@mdswartz The outward gravitational acceleration induced on a spherical box of radius $r$ is $g=H_0^2\Omega_\Lambda r$, where $H_0\simeq 68$ km/s/Mpc is the Hubble constant and $\Omega_\Lambda\simeq 0.69$ is the dark energy density parameter. That works out to be about $3\times 10^{-36}r/\mathrm{sec}^2$ (so if the radius were 1 meter, the acceleration would be $3\times 10^{-36} \mathrm{m}/\mathrm{s}^2$).

if the box has the size of the Hubblesphere the force in order to stay constant should be infinite since it would require local speed of light to keep a contant distance, while in your equation g stays finite even if the box was larger than that. the proper acceleration or force required to stay stationary at distance r is F=cr√(((H²(c-Hr)+Ḣc)(H²(c+Hr)+Ḣc))/(c²-r²H²)²) for a time dependend H and F=cH²r/√(c²-r²H²) for a constant H (Ḣ=0), so if the diameter of the box was c/H the force would be infinite (F=1/0).

Sten wrote: "without dark energy, there would be no expansion force on the box, even as the Universe expands" - that is also wrong, the proper acceleration F=√|gᵤᵥaᵘaᵛ| does not care where the H and Ḣ come from. the required force to stay stationary relative to another object at distance r=c/H is always infinite, even without dark energy, since the equation for the proper acceleration of a stationary object always has the recessional Lorentzfactor √(c²-r²H²) in the denominator.

@Yukterez I'm working in the subhorizon limit (will edit to clarify). Note that your claims are not objectively true because outside the subhorizon limit, distances and speeds are not uniquely defined.

not uniquely since you can always construct some abstract coordinates, but the standard definition of the distance that works to the particle horizon and beyond is to add up rulers who are locally at rest with respect to the Hubbleflow, and the peculiar velocity is relative to one of those, while the recessional velocity is how much more rulers you need per time interval. you can always add up the rulers since every ruler always has a neighbouring ruler, and the coordinate time is simply the proper time of a comoving observer since the big bang.

Sure, you can make claims using standard coordinate systems. They are still not objective claims (and being locked into thinking about one coordinate system is exactly what leads to the expanding space misconception!)

anyways, the force on the box is an invariant, that's the same in all coordinates since the F=√|gᵤᵥaᵘaᵛ|  can handle all possible gᵤᵥ.

However, the notion of stationary is not.

That is already the case with Newton, you can always switch to a frame where the former stationary object is moving, but here we're talking about the left side of the box being stationary relative to its right side (or the other way around since right and left are relative as well), which requires the speed of light relative to a local observer at the Hubbleradius, so the box has to be smaller than that in order to be static.

In addition to the choice of what is stationary (the threading) is the choice of what is at constant time (the slicing; see https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/53836/47607). Your conclusion results from your choice of slicing.
